# Disable kde screen scaling for specific applications?

Tags: linux, debian, display, kde, kde-plasma-5

```
4.9.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1 (2017-03-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
kde-plasma-desktop                            5:92
```

This is my problem, I have a high density display so I need to scale my screen to 1.5 to make it usable.

This is screen scaling feature to which I am referring:
[image]

But I also use Android AVDs which don't respond well to the screen scaling (see my p[ost about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118971/android-avds-not-working-with-hardware-acceleration/44119846#44119846))

So what do I do about apps that break when the screen is scaled? Can I disable scaling for a specific application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1` to disable scaling for that application.

Example: `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1 emulator -avd n5 -verbose`

Alternatively, you may consider reverting the scaling, then starting other applications with `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5`.

> [High DPI Displays | QT 5.8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt)
>
> QT_SCALE_FACTOR [numeric] defines a global scale factor for the whole
>   application, including point sized fonts.

Comment: So I actually had to scale it by QT_SCALE_FACTOR=.66. Now is that because I already had my desktop scaled to 1.5 and the QT_SCALE_FACTOR is relative to the current scaling size?

Comment: Unsure.  I didn't play around enough with the setting to determine that.

Comment: `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=.66` didn't work but `GDK_SCALE=.66` worked

Comment: This does not seem to work for KDE with wayland. Bug report https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=441705